# How to fix position of an iframe such that it also changes its TOP level when scrolled?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to fix the position of an iframe element. The problem is, if I keep the position 'STICKY' it will cover the space as well and push the elements below. So, the best possible value is the 'ABSOLUTE' position.

But now if I keep the position absolute it doesn't move along as I scroll. So neither sticky nor absolute work perfectly.

I want the Iframe to be on top of the texts below the input search, and it should scroll along with the screen. Just like the input element with position sticky does.

```
<h1><center>Heading</center></h1>

<input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
<iframe id="search-box" src="https://www.google.com/search?igu=1&ei=&q="></iframe>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<style>
input#search {
 position: sticky;
 top: 43px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 3px 5px;
 font-size: 20px;
 background: #f1f1f1;
}

iframe#search-box {
 position: absolute;
 left: 5%; top: 76px;
 width: 90%;
 height: 360px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Try to use outer *wrapper* with `position: relative` to limit STICKY / ABSOLUTE positioning of inner elements.

Comment: What does outer wrapper mean?

Answer (score 0):

Adding both to the input and iframe elements under a common div and then adding the sticky position value to it solved the problem!

```css
div#container {
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
}
/* It is easier to add the position property to the parent tag directly. */

input#search {
 width: 100%; /* To cover the whole area */
 padding: 3px 5px;
 font-size: 20px;
 background: #f1f1f1;
}

iframe#search-box {
 position: absolute; /* We need to add this to help position the left & top property of the element. Else it would just be on the top of container tag. */
 left: 5%; top: 32px;
 width: 90%; height: 360px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
/* Keep width less than 100% to make it look in the middle. And keep left in '%' so that it will change as the size of window. */
```

```html
<h1><center>Heading</center></h1>

<div id="container">
 <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
 <iframe id="search-box" src="https://www.google.com/search?igu=1&ei=&q="></iframe>
</div>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to create `.wrapper` for STICKY block explicitly, it also can limit it`s contents (max-width/height) and lock positioning of STICKY element inside.

If you hit "preview" button - paragraphs will be under STICKY because of limited height.

If You want to avoid it - use FIXED positioning and additive rule `margin-top:400px` (height of STICKY block) for 1st paragraph.

```css
.wrapper{
 position:relativer;
}
.sticky{
 position:sticky;
 top: 43px;
}

input#search {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 3px 5px;
 font-size: 20px;
 background: #f1f1f1;
}

iframe#search-box {
 left: 5%; top: 76px;
 width: 90%;
 height: 360px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

p{
outline:1px dashed #555; /* to track its "underflow" */
}

/* alternative with FIXED positioning*/
/*


.sticky{
 position:fixed;
 top: 60px; 
}

#first-p{
 margin-top:400px;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<h1><center>Heading</center></h1>
<div class="sticky">
  <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
  <iframe id="search-box" src="https://www.google.com/search?igu=1&ei=&q="></iframe>
</div>

<p id="first-p">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>


</div>
```

Comment: The iframe tag needs to have a position added to it for the left & top tags to work. Since there is no position the tags won't work.

Comment: Also, you misspelled the position 'relative' in div#wrapper.

Comment: And it's way easier if we put the whole section in one parent and add the sticky property to the parent tag.